# $\frac{b^{n+1}}{a^n} \ge (n+1) \cdot b - n \cdot a$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $\frac{b^{n+1}}{a^n} \ge (n+1)\cdot b - n \cdot a$ if $a, b \ge 0$ and n - natural number.
I tried to use Bernoulli's inequality:
$\gamma = b - a$.
$(1 + \frac{\gamma}{a})^n \cdot (\gamma +a) \ge n * \gamma + \gamma + a$.
Thus,

$\gamma + a * \gamma + \frac{\gamma ^ 2 * n}{a} + \gamma * n \ge n*\gamma + \gamma + a$

$a * \gamma + \frac{\gamma ^ 2 * n}{a} \ge a$

And then I stuck..

Comment: The inequality is not true unless you specify the range of $a,b$. For example, If $n=1,a=-1, b=0$ it is false.

Comment: Oh, sure, forgot about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM inequality on $n$ $a^{n+1}$ and $1$ $b^{n+1}$,$$na^{n+1}+b^{n+1}\ge(n+1)a^nb$$Now divide both sides by $a^n$ to get your inequality.